# ER Diagrams - Same relationship with two different entities

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-relationship

If a given entity has the same relationship with two other entities, how do I represent it in an ER diagram?

The particular problem I am dealing with is for a typical social network, such that:

1. 'Users' create 'Groups'
2. 'Users' create 'Posts'
3. 'Posts' may be visible to certain 'Users' and/or 'Groups'.

Users, Posts and Groups are the entities that I have drawn. I need help in drawing the 'visibility' relationship. Do I draw 2 'visible to' relations, one each for 'Users' and 'Posts'? Or do I draw a single relationship and branch it to users and groups respectively?

Comment: Read about ternary relations.

Answer (score 1):

The visibility relationship sounds like a case of generalization/specialization.  Perhaps visibility applies to "readers" and "readers" is a generalization of "users" and "groups".  I'm not sure if this really applies in your case.  It's your call.

If you decide that it does apply, you can look up gen/spec in EERD (Extended Entity Relationship Diagramming) to see how to diagram it.

When you get around to designing tables to store this data, you may want to visit these tags:

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)